# Parse JsonBuilder to JsonSlurper preserving backslashes in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I want to parse a JSON which I have as JsonBuilder object. This JSON contains some backslashes. Here is what I am doing

```
b = new JsonBuilder(json).toPrettyString();
s = new JsonSlurper().parseText(b);
```

But I get this error

`Expected a value or a closing curly brace } on line: 8, column: 27.`

This is happening because `toPrettyString` removes the backslashes (escape charachers) from my JsonBuilder String. Is there any way I can preserve the backslashes?

Answer (score 0):

```
import groovy.json.*;

def json =[a:"aa\naa",b:'bb\tbb"bb']

def b = new JsonBuilder(json).toPrettyString();
println b
```

gives fine result:

```
{
    "a": "aa\naa",
    "b": "bb\tbb\"bb"
}
```

provide your example

Comment: Your code is giving an error here: https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5140871641038848

Comment: the problem in this service  https://groovyconsole.appspot.com. the simple code `println '{"b\\"}'` that should print out `{"b\"}` throws javascript error. use a standard `groovyconsole` from your groovy installation to test your scripts : http://groovy-lang.org/groovyconsole.html